# DC.js Stacked Line Chart not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

Is there a more complete tutorial or guide to creating charts with dc.js than what is offered in their [documentation](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html)? I'm trying to create a simple line chart with 2 stacked levels. I'm making use of the following csv:

[image]

I want the WasteDate to be on the x-axis and the WasteData to be on the y-axis. Further I want one layer to be of the WasteFunction Minimisation and the other to be of the WasteFunction Disposal. This should give me something like the following (very roughly):

[image]

Now, as I understand it, I need to create a dimension for the x-axis using crossfilter and then a filtered dimension for my 2 stacks.

The dimension for the x-axis will be the dates:

```
// dimension by month
var Date_dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.WasteDate;
});

// Get min/max date for x-axis
var minDate = Date_dim.bottom(1)[0].WasteDate;
var maxDate = Date_dim.top(1)[0].WasteDate;
```

Then I need to create a dimension for the y-axis, then filter it for each of my stacks?

```
// WasteType dimension
var WasteFunction_dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.WasteFunction;
});

// Minimisation Filter
var WasteFunction_Disposal = WasteFunction_dim.filter("Disposal");

// Disposal Filter
var WasteFunction_Minimisation = WasteFunction_dim.filter("Minimisation");
```

Then I should be able to use these to setup the chart:

```
moveChart
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(900)
    .height(200)
    .dimension(Date_dim)
    .group(WasteFunction_Minimisation, 'Minimisation')
    .stack(WasteFunction_Disposal, 'Disposal')
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]));
```

Now, I can't get passed this error on the `RenderAll()` function:

[image]

---

The full code:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var moveChart = dc.lineChart('#monthly-move-chart');

    d3.csv('minimisation-vs-disposal.csv', function(data) {
      /* format the csv file a bit */
      var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%d/%M/%Y');
      var numberFormat = d3.format('.2f');

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.WasteDate);
        d.WasteData = +d.WasteData // coerce to number
      });

      // Cross Filter instance
      var ndx = crossfilter(data);
      var all = ndx.groupAll();

      // dimension by month
      var Date_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.WasteDate;
      });

      // Get min/max date for x-axis
      var minDate = Date_dim.bottom(1)[0].WasteDate;
      var maxDate = Date_dim.top(1)[0].WasteDate;

      // Waste Data dimension
      var WasteData_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.WasteData;
      });

      // WasteType dimension
      var WasteFunction_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.WasteFunction;
      });

      // Minimisation Filter
      var WasteFunction_Disposal = WasteFunction_dim.filter("Disposal");

      // Disposal Filter
      var WasteFunction_Minimisation = WasteFunction_dim.filter("Minimisation");

      moveChart
        .renderArea(true)
        .width(900)
        .height(200)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .dimension(Date_dim)
        .group(WasteFunction_Minimisation, 'Minimisation')
        .stack(WasteFunction_Disposal, 'Disposal')
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]));

      dc.renderAll();
    });
  });

< /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="monthly-move-chart">
  <strong>Waste minimisation chart</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, dc.js does not have much documentation. Someone could write a book but it hasn't happened. People mostly rely on examples to get started, and the [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) is a good first read.

The biggest problem in your code is that those are not crossfilter groups. You really need to learn the crossfilter concepts to use dc.js effectively. Crossfilter has [very strong documentation](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference), but it's also very dense and you'll have to read it a few times.

Feel free to join us on the [dc.js user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups%23!forum/dc-js-user-group) if you want to talk it through to get a better understanding. It does take a while to get the idea but it's worth it!